# accessing request data outside a request

Tags: node.js, express

My request header contains data like `Authorization`. I am trying to get that from an event that sends out a notification.

I typically access the header like: `var auth = req.get('Authorization');`

But needing to access it from a models event which doesn't have any `req` is not possible with that code.

So what are the possible ways to achieve something like this?

---

Updated with recommendation from comments.

So technically I have a controller like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    req.get('Authorization');
    // save some model data
});
```

Now I have a model that has a `onSaving` event. When the model emits the event. I run some code.

This code requires the `Authorization` header but I cannot get it from anywhere because it is only available on the `req`. And the model is another file and I am using an ORM for MYSQL.

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more detail from your code to get anywhere.  The short answer is you have to work with scope to make sure the data, or access to it, is in scope where you need it.  That means either assigning it to a higher level scope where you *do* have the `req` object, or passing it into your model.

Comment: Got same problem with a Bookshelf model where I need a relation to filter on Authenticated user available in request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have much details about your question, but this may be the answer:

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();


eventEmitter.on('auth', function( params ){
    var req = params.req,
        res = params.res,
        auth = params.auth;
    // Do something with auth or req/res here...
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    var auth = req.get('Authorization');
    // save some model data
    eventEmitter.emit('auth', {
        req: req,
        req: res,
        auth: auth
    });
});
```

Comment: I already have a event emitter with the model ORM I am using. But I'll try this when I get back.